# Bind any key (by keycode) to an action using Knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm looking for a method to bind many different keys to different actions/functions in my viewmodel.

I've found this [example](http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2011/10/11/knockoutjs-custom-binding-for-invoking-an-action-with-enter-key.aspx) where a binding handler is used to bind actions to the enter-key.

But how do I modify this handler to also support a supplied key-code? I'd like to be able to  use the same handler for all kinds of keys and preferably also combined with modifier keys.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.executeOnEnter = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        var allBindings = allBindingsAccessor();
        $(element).keypress(function (event) {
            var keyCode = (event.which ? event.which : event.keyCode);
            if (keyCode === 13) {
                allBindings.executeOnEnter.call(viewModel);
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        });
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.actionKey = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, data) {
        var handler = function(data, event) {
            var keys = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(allBindings().keys) || [13]; //default to Enter Key
            if (!Array.isArray(keys))
                keys = [keys];
            if (keys.indexOf(event.keyCode) > -1) {
                valueAccessor().call(data, data, event);
            };
        };
        var newValueAccessor = function() {
            return { keyup: handler };
        };
        ko.bindingHandlers.event.init(element, newValueAccessor, allBindings, data);
    }
};
```

and you can use this binding in like this:

```
Observable Keys: <input data-bind="actionKey: action, keys: keyCodes" /><br/>
Inline Keys: <input data-bind="actionKey: action, keys: [33, 34]" /><br/>
Inline Key: <input data-bind="actionKey: action, keys: 33" /><br/>
Default Keys: <input data-bind="actionKey: action" /><br/>
```

Here is [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tyrsius/SuaNe/1/) demonstrating this binding.

Comment: Very nice but doesn't work with knockout 3.x Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '$data' of undefined

Comment: If the input is binding to the value of an observable it's important to add the `valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'` binding. Without this binding if a user types text then hits enter, the onblur event is not raised prior to `actionKey` binding resulting in the observable returning an unexpected value and not the current text.