# keyup and keydown is not working on table having knockout binding

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I need to scroll on table rows using key up and key down . For that I need to capture key events on table div. If I replace 'keyup' with 'click' event, its working fine but same piece of code is not working for key up and key down. I am unable to figure out the issue.

```
$('#patientWL').on('keyup', '.bodyTable tbody tr', function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 38) {
        alert('key up');
    } else if (e.keyCode == 40) {
        alert('key down');
    }
});
```

Working fiddle of my problem can be seen [here](http://jsfiddle.net/LvEdk/18/)

Comment: Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/Alfie/LvEdk/19/

Comment: @Anton In my project , only a part of browser window contains that particular table so the key event should be called on that div only . If I am clicking outside that table then also that keyevent will be called with 'document' which is undesirable

Comment: Then you'll need to do a workaround by adding tabindex like Sunny's answer. Here's an example http://jsfiddle.net/Alfie/LvEdk/20/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note that this is not a knockout specific problem. The problem is with the way elements handle keyup/down/press events.

A `table` (or `tr`, `td`) by default cannot be given focus. However, you can change that by adding a `tabindex` attribute:

```
<tr tabindex="0" id="example"></tr>
```

You can then give the `tr` focus, and also blur it with the `hover` event:

```
$("#example").hover(function() {
    this.focus();
}, function() {
    this.blur();
}).keydown(function(e) {
    alert(e.keyCode);
});
```

When the `tr` has focus, it will accept keyboard events. Look at a sample [here.](http://jsfiddle.net/bCxpb/)

Comment: As per your example , tab index need to be added but in my case rows are getting generated dynamically. so how to add tab index dynamically?

Comment: Thanks alot I understood by the changes made by Anton in my fiddle

Comment: In my application , I have a page for adding new patients and once user click on save it will be showed in table of my fiddle and that particular record will have focus also but now If I am doing keypress event , its not working and as soon as I click on any record it works fine . So how to put explicit focus on my fiddle table.Kindly help

Comment: I suggest create a new question showing what you have done, and what you are trying to achieve, that way others can also help with the issue.

Comment: After login into application , already added patient records will be shown and if any record is clicked , I am able to scroll using keyup/down (after setting tab index).Now If I click on Add Patient button present on current screen , i'll be navigated to new screen where after entering details , i can save patient record which will be displayed on my previous screen of patient records with focus on that particular record but now keyUp/Down is not working.How to handle this.did u understand my scenario?

Comment: I am able to handle that scenario after putting explicit focus by using $('.bodyTableWrapper').focus();

Comment: Excellent. I understood the problem. Yes the solution you found is decent.

Answer (score 0):

Although that's an old question, it's worth adding here a custom binding handler implementation (based on these posts: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16970751/how-to-bind-up-and-down-arrow-key-to-enable-navigating-through-table-rows/16970960), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15977496/bind-any-key-by-keycode-to-an-action-using-knockout)):

```js
ko.bindingHandlers.mapKeysToActions = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, data) {
        var handler = function (data, event) {
            var keysAndActions = valueAccessor();
            if (Object.keys(keysAndActions).indexOf(event.keyCode.toString()) > -1) {
                keysAndActions[event.keyCode].call();
            };
        };
        var newValueAccessor = function () {
            return { keyup: handler };
        };
        ko.applyBindingAccessorsToNode(element, {
            event: newValueAccessor
        });
    }
};
var myModel = function () {
  var self = this;
  self.selectResult = function (item) {
    self.selectedResult(item);
  };
  self.setSelected = function ($data, $element) {
    var isSelected = self.selectedResult() == $data;
    if (isSelected) $($element).focus();
    return isSelected;
  };
  self.selectedResult = ko.observable();
  self.searchResults = ko.observableArray([
    { data1: "1", data2: "1" }, { data1: "2", data2: "2" }, { data1: "3", data2: "3" }
  ]);
  self.selectPrevious = function () {
    var index = self.searchResults().indexOf(self.selectedResult()) - 1;
    if (index < 0) index = 0;
    self.selectedResult(self.searchResults()[index]);
  };
  self.selectNext = function () {
    var index = self.searchResults().indexOf(self.selectedResult()) + 1;
    if (index >= self.searchResults().length) index = self.searchResults().length - 1;
    self.selectedResult(self.searchResults()[index]);
  };
  self.keysAndActions = {
    '38': self.selectPrevious,
    '40': self.selectNext
  };
};
ko.applyBindings(new myModel());
```

```css
.btn-info {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
   <th>&nbsp;</th>
   <th>table header 1</th>
   <th>table header 2</th>
 </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: searchResults">
 <tr tabindex="0" 
        data-bind="click: $parent.selectResult, 
                   css: { 'btn-info': $parent.setSelected($data, $element) }, 
                   mapKeysToActions: $parent.keysAndActions">
   <td data-bind="text: data1"></td>
   <td data-bind="text: data2"></td>
 </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```